Python requests put to update image always give a 400. Im following the documentation
im having this issue:
My code is this
import requests
import json
import re

# Define your Shopify store's API key and password
API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
API_TOKEN = 'xxxx_xxxxxxxxxcd7'

SHOPIFY_DOMAIN = 'https://www.xxxx.xxx/'

headers = {
    'X-Shopify-Access-Token': API_TOKEN,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

# Define the endpoint URL
endpoint = 'https://www.xxxxx/admin/api/2024-04/products/9190309691717/images/53245809295685.json'

# Define the new alt text
new_alt_text = "#title-#seren.earth-#variantSKU"

# Prepare the request body
body = {
    'image': {
        "product_id": 9190309691717,
        "id": 53245809295685,  # Include the image ID,
        "alt": 'variantSKU',
    }
}



# Send the PUT request
response = requests.put(endpoint, headers=headers, json=body)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.content)
# Check the response status
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(f"Alt text updated successfully for image 9190309691717")
else:
    print(f"Failed to update alt text for image 9190309691717. Response: {response.text}")

But im always getting this error:
400
b'{"errors":{"image":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}'
Failed to update alt text for image 9190309691717. Response: {"errors":{"image":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}
What am i missing? Do you see any errors?

Please put a link to the documentation, so we can see the expected format.

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2024-04/resources/product

The documentation says the endpoint should be .../products/{product_id}.json, but you are using .../products/9190309691717/images/53245809295685.json.  Why?

/admin/api/2024-04/products/632910392/images/850703190.json
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2024-04/resources/product-image#put-products-product-id-images-image-id

product_id is already included in the url.  Why do you also have it in the json data?

Also, this isn't the cause of the error, but why are you bothering to define the new_alt_text variable if you aren't going to actually use it?

i will use it..just doing tests before i use it. It seems there is an issue with the .json. It does not take the imageId param
